# Change font type in a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

hi i try to change the font type in a div. where there are 2  button  of which user can change the font type. the font type option is in css

```
.fontType1{font:"Lucida Handwriting";}    
.fontType2{font:"Comic Sans MS";}
```

button:

```
<div id="greet"></div>
<div  title="fontType1" >Lucida</div>
<div  title="fontType2" >comic</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$("div").click(function (){
    $("#greet").removeClass(font);
    var font = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#greet").addClass(font);
});
```

help please...

Comment: I trust there is code missing which tells the code what the original font class to remove is?

Comment: button? it must be <input type="button> use class=".." if you want they work.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab here, but perhaps:

```
.fontType1{font-family:"Lucida Handwriting";}    
.fontType2{font-family:"Comic Sans MS";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `font-family` instead of `font`:

```
.fontType1{font-family:"Lucida Handwriting";}
.fontType2{font-family:"Comic Sans MS";}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAsyK/

Answer (score 0):

You're using a variable named `font` before declaring it when you call `removeClass`. Try something like

```
$("div").click(function (){
    var old_font = $('#greet').data('current_font');
    if (old_font) {
       $("#greet").removeClass(old_font);
    }
    var font = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#greet").addClass(font).data('current_font', font);
});
```

Also, as others pointed out, if you should only set the font family, use the `font-family` property. The `font` property is for defining [all the font properties in one declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_font.asp)

```
.fontTypeX {font-family:"Arial";}
```

BTW: have you heard about [browser safe fonts](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html)?

Answer (score -1):

I think you better should google with Jquery Class Switcher as there is a plugin that can help you switch class in a single statement.